# Duplicate Records in when Spark Tasks fails

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am facing duplicate records in the Cassandra table when the spark tasks fails and it is restarted again. Schema of the table that I am trying to insert.

```
CREATE TABLE duplicate_record (object_id bigint,entity_key timeuuid,
PRIMARY KEY (object_id, entity_key));
```

Sample Duplicate Records in the table

```
1181592431 uuid
1181592431 uuid1
8082869622 uuid2
8082869622 uuid3
```

I have a df which is produced by the left join between Oracle and Cassandra. So we have already existing records in Cassandra and new records which are generated from Oracle.
I apply a map of each record to see if the entity_id exists. If it exists then use it else for new records create fresh entity_id and then do the save. I am using saveToCassandra to insert this df to Cassandra.

When the task fails and is restarted, already inserted records are being inserted again with a different entity_key. I guess the inserted record during the successful execution is not available when the task is resubmitted resulting in duplicate records.

Comment: Do you restart full spark task or only writing to Cassandra part? Also what is your replication factor and consistency levels on write/read?

Comment: We do not have a control on the tasking right. Spark restarts the complete task from the begining. My understandinf might be wrong here as well.RF = 3 and Consistency level for read/writes is QUORUM.

Comment: How are your entity keys generated? Can you have them based on the actual data rather than being randomly created each time?

Comment: We can have it generated based on the actual data. In that case as well, if the inserted data is not fetched when the spark task is restarted, we are not able to find the inserted data. This is resulting in duplicate records. I might be missing something here. Correcting the info provided earlier CL for this is LOCAL_ONE. and RF =3.

Comment: Change CL to LOCAL_QUORUM and see if the issue continues

Answer (score 0):

Spark Speculative Execution can cause duplicate records, so pls turn it to false.

still if this happens then it could be due to some spark nodes/tasks getting restarted… there was a Spark bug for duplicate record commit, its resolved in 2.1.3 version:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24589

pls ensure you are running on 2.1.3+.